# Correct classpath of your application so it contains compatible versions of classes org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters and org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters.configurePartConverters(HttpMessageConverters.java:156)

The following method did not exist:

    org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.getPartConverters()Ljava/util/List;

The calling method's class, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters, was loaded from the following location:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/2.6.3/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.3.jar!/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/http/HttpMessageConverters.class

The called method's class, org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/5.2.3.RELEASE/spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/http/converter/support/AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.class

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter: file:/C:/Users/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/5.2.3.RELEASE/spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar
    org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter: file:/C:/Users/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/5.2.3.RELEASE/spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

showing this error after adding **spring-web** dependency

Comment: Remove `spring-web` dependency. Add `spring-boot-starter-web` as a dependency. You are mixing Spring 5.2 and 5.3 with this setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed adding `spring-web` from Spring 5.2 will fail. This is because Spring Boot 2.6.x uses Spring 5.3. One should never mix modules from different versions of a framework. Regardless which framework, as that will lead to weird bugs, incompatibility errors (like this one) and more ...

To fix, replace the `spring-web` dependency with `spring-boot-starter-web` to get the correct version.

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```